# PHP Extensions are disabled by default using Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm developing a Laravel application using Docker. I use multiple containers for different services; App (PHP), Webserver (Nginx), Relational Database (MySql) and In-Memory Database (Redis).

I've written a Dockerfile for App service using php:8.1-fpm as the base image. The problem is when I bring up the container and go to /usr/local/etc/php folder to check the installed extensions (I tried to use FFI extension and it turned out that it is disabled), I found two files: php.ini-development and php.ini-production. When I executed *cat* command on them, I found out that almost all the extensions are disabled by default in both of them.

So my question is do I need to enable them myself each time I bring up the container? Isn't there a better way?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install apt-utils procps -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl libgmp-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev libnghttp2-dev libffi-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl soap gmp bcmath ffi
    # Install additional extension
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/ && cd /usr/src/php/ext/ \
    && pecl bundle ev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) ev
    # Install PrimeModule for AuthKey generation speedup
RUN git clone https://github.com/danog/PrimeModule-ext \
    && cd PrimeModule-ext && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd ../  \
    && rm -rf PrimeModule-ext/
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apt-get autoremove --purge -y && apt-get autoclean -y && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /usr/src

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install nodejs
# RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - 
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And Here is the first part of php.ini-development file (As it is a long file, I didn't copy all lines of the file):

```
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See https://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xsl

;zend_extension=opcache
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the docker-php-ext-install method but you can likely download your own php.ini or modify the existing one in the Dockerfile just like all the other setup steps you're performing there.

Comment: @Devon I've written this Dockerfile based on other Dockerfiles that I've seen so far. None of them changed anything about php.ini.